# SSRS Summing Group Variables outside of the group

Tags: reporting-services

I have succeeded in building a number of group variables within an SSRS report, however what I want to do now is to use that variable outside of the group.

eg - I have a variable that calculates a payment within one dataset, and another one that calculates a payment within another dataset.

The first would be `=Variables!QualityPayment.Value`, the second would be `=Variables!RevenuePayment.Value`. Revenue and Quality are displayed in different SSRS tables.

I want to add the Quality Payment and Revenue Payment together, but when I try and put them outside of the table I get the error message

*'Expressions can only refer to a Variable declared within the same grouping scope, a containing grouping scope, or those declared on the report.'*

How do I go about adding the two together?

Thanks in advance

Jon

Answer (score 2):

What I would do would be to use the group variable just as a way to add the values to an external variable, declared on the VB Code section of the report:

On the Report Properties -> Code section you use the following code:

```
Dim variable1 AS Integer
Function addValue(ByVal value AS Integer)
    variable1 += value
End Function

Function getValue()
    return variable1
End Function
```

Then on the group variable section of the tablix, you just call `addValue(somefield)` and when you need to access the calculated value you can do it from outside the group by calling the `getValue` function.

Comment: i can't believe this amazing answer is upvoted so less. this answer saved me from suicide xD

Comment: Could you provide more details for how to SUM the group variables? I have a variable I am referencing in a tablix textbox as `Variables!varBudgetVariance.Value`.  I want to calculate totals via SUM in a textbox below the group but when I use the expression `SUM(Variables!varBudgetVariance.Value)` I get this error: *"Variable values cannot be used in aggregate functions"*.  If I add your functions, `addValue` and `getValue` to the report code, how do I call them in the tablix??

Comment: You go to your tablix and in Tablix Group Properties create a variable and the value will be the call to the addValue function with whatever fields you need: Code.addValue(Fields!my_field). Then on your textbox you call the getValue function: Code.getValue()

Comment: Okay thanks.  I did this and it worked kind of.  Thoughts on how to correct these issues?  ***Good:*** (1) The total is now printed in the group footer and at-a-glance looks correct with tablix footer expression `Code.getLWSBeginLifetimeExpense()`.  ***Bad:*** There are some odd issues now such as (1) When I print the variable value in the group table `Variables!varLWSBegin_LifetimeExpense.Value` the values are blank throughout the tablix dataset; (2) When I export from browser render to excel the group footer values change and are incorrect (e.g. from "1,214,284" to "0").

Comment: In comme above, I am using using GroupVar expression `Code.addLWSBeginLifetimeExpense(CDbl(
IIF(Parameters!boolUseLwsBalance.Value = false, 0,
Lookup(Fields!ProjectId.Value, Fields!ProjectId.Value, Fields!LWSBegin_LifetimeExpense.Value, "dsCAPEXAmountsCustomDataUpload"))
))` and footer textbox expression `Code.getLWSBeginLifetimeExpense()`.

Comment: In comment above, I am using this VB code: `Public totalLWSBeginLifetimeExpense as Integer Public Function getLWSBeginLifetimeExpense()
 return totalLWSBeginLifetimeExpense
End Function

Public Function addLWSBeginLifetimeExpense(ByVal thisLWSBeginLifetimeExpense AS Integer )
 totalLWSBeginLifetimeExpense = totalLWSBeginLifetimeExpense + thisLWSBeginLifetimeExpense
End Function`

Comment: Fixed the group variable value by returning "thisLWSBeginLifetimeExpense" within the add function like this: `Public Function addLWSBeginLifetimeExpense(ByVal thisLWSBeginLifetimeExpense AS Integer )
 totalLWSBeginLifetimeExpense = totalLWSBeginLifetimeExpense + thisLWSBeginLifetimeExpense
 return thisLWSBeginLifetimeExpense
End Function`.  Still need to fix totals not printing when exporting to Excel.

Comment: Do you now why export to Excel and the `Code.getTotal` value is 0? The value prints correctly on the interactive page but is 0 when exported. If I change `Dim` to `Dim Public Shared` the zeros go away. But then the variable value are added to each other every time the report is run.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Sorry, don't remember that case, so would have to check and don't have my laptop with me right now.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that both datasets are accessing the same database, I suggest combining the two datasets into a single dataset.

Answer (score 0):

In your definition of the variables, make sure that any aggregate functions have the dataset specified for the scope, i.e.:

```
=SUM(Fields!MyFieldName.Value, "DataSet1") / 12
```